# Efficient way to create sub set from an existing one?

Tags: java, performance, oop

I'm searching for a good solution to create a subset from a existing set. 
For example, i have a set with 1000 Objects (or whatever..) and i need to make a "team" that is made of 100 Objects from that main set.
I'm working with JAVA and i know that if I just create another array with that 100 Objects that will do.

Assuming that i have a class A, a class B and a Class C. Class B contains the set and Class C contains the subset (team..wtv) and the set is made of Class A objects. My problem is that Class A "needs to know" if it makes part of an Object of Class C an what specific instance of Class C he is part of.

I hope i was clearly enough to explain my situation and get some help.

Thank you ;]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that class `A` has a method to associate an instance of `C` with `A`, like in a parent/child relation.

```
class A {
   void setParent(Object obj);
   Object getParent();
}
```

In this case, after you filter the original set contained in B, use `addA` or `setMySet` to associate your subset with `C`:

```
class C {
   private Set<A> mySet;

   public void addA(A a) {
      mySet.add(a);
      a.setParent(this);
   }

   public void setMySet(Set<A> subset) {
      mySet = new HashSet<A>(subSet);
      for(A a in subSet) {
         a.setParent(this);
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: can we have a complete example